# Parse error on last line for some reason?

Tags: php, html

Can't figure out why after much tinkering, would appreciate the help:

```
<?php
// Fetch the user row from the query above
$userData = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$password = $userData["password"];

    if(isset($_POST['password2'])){
        $p2 = $_POST['password2'];
        }


    $password2 = sha1($p2);

// Ajax calls this REGISTRATION code to execute
if($password2 == $password){
// GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
$personname = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['personname']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['email']);
$address_line1 = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['address_line1']);
$address_line2 = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['address_line2']);
$address_city = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['address_city']);
$address_state = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['address_state']);
$address_zip = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['address_zip']);
$address_country = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '',   $_POST['address_country']);
```

//////// DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR EMAIL

```
    $sql1 = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";

    if($email =! email){
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
        $email_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if ($email_check > 0){ 
        echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
        exit();
}
```

////////// FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING

```
else if($personname == "" || $email == "" || $password == "" ||   $address_country == "" || $address_line1 == "" || $address_line2 == "" || $address_city == "" || $address_state == "" || $address_zip == ""){
    echo "The form submission is missing values.";
    exit();
}

    else {
```

//////// END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
//////// Begin Replacement of data into the database

//////Add user info into the database table for the main site table

```
$query = "UPDATE users (personname, email, address_line1, address_line2, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country)
            VALUES('$personname','$email','$address_line1','$address_line2','$address_city','$address_state','$address_zip','$address_country')
            WHERE id = '$id'";

            if(mysql_query($query)){
                echo "updated";
                header("location: user.php?id=".$_SESSION["id"]);
                } else{ echo "fail";}

    }
exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there isn't a closing brace `}` for `if($password2 == $password){` which may belong right after `$address_country...`. However, your bracing's a bit off, and the last `}` after `exit;` should be moved up, along with a few others. The one for `if($email =! email){` for instance.

You're also mixing APIs with `if(mysql_query($query))` that needs to be `if(mysqli_query($db_conx, $query))` and `MYSQL_ASSOC` to `MYSQLI_ASSOC`. Those different MySQL functions do not intermix with each other. Plus, make sure you've started the session, since you are using sessions.

Then there's this line `if($email =! email){` - `email` is treated as a [**constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php), and is also incorrect. It should read as `if($email != email){`. However, I don't know which variable (or string) you're wanting to use/check for, or even from a row in your table.

Then this query's variable `$sql1` - It's sitting in limbo. I've no idea what you wish to do with that.

If you're wanting to match a row against "email", then you will need to do just that, is fetch the row from DB.

- Consult: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

*See footnotes*

Try the following, where I've re-arranged your bracing:

***Sidenote:*** Check what you wish to do about what I said above, in regards to `email` being a constant. It hasn't been changed below.

```
<?php
// Fetch the user row from the query above
$userData = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$password = $userData["password"];

    if(isset($_POST['password2'])){
        $p2 = $_POST['password2'];
        }


    $password2 = sha1($p2);

// Ajax calls this REGISTRATION code to execute
if($password2 == $password){
// GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
$personname = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['personname']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['email']);
$address_line1 = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['address_line1']);
$address_line2 = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['address_line2']);
$address_city = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['address_city']);
$address_state = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['address_state']);
$address_zip = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['address_zip']);
$address_country = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '',   $_POST['address_country']);
}

//////// DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR EMAIL

    $sql1 = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";

// unsure what you want to do here
    if($email != email){
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
        $email_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if ($email_check > 0){
        echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
        exit();
        }
}

////////// FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING

else if($personname == "" || $email == "" || $password == "" ||   $address_country == "" || $address_line1 == "" || $address_line2 == "" || $address_city == "" || $address_state == "" || $address_zip == ""){
    echo "The form submission is missing values.";
    exit();
}

    else {

//////// END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING //////// Begin Replacement of data into the database

//////Add user info into the database table for the main site table

$query = "UPDATE users (personname, email, address_line1, address_line2, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country)
            VALUES('$personname','$email','$address_line1','$address_line2','$address_city','$address_state','$address_zip','$address_country')
            WHERE id = '$id'";

            if(mysqli_query($db_conx, $query))
                echo "updated";
                header("location: user.php?id=".$_SESSION["id"]);
                } else{ echo "fail";}

    }
exit();

?>
```

---

Sidenote:

You're using `UPDATE users...` that isn't the way UPDATE works.

The syntax is `UPDATE table SET column_x = '$var'`

Read up on UPDATE:

- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-data.aspx

I.e. from that page:

```
 UPDATE [LOW_ PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_name [, table_name...]
SET column_name1 = expr1
     [, column_name2=expr2 ...]
[WHERE condition]
```

If it's not an UPDATE you wish to do, then use `INSERT INTO`, which I'm leaning more towards to.

---

- Add `or die(mysqli_error($db_conx))` to `mysqli_query()` and you will see the error(s).

---

**Footnotes:**

Here is an example on fetching a row:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$email_row = $row['email'];
```

Then you can do:

```
if($email != $email_row){...}
```